# A problem dealing with homeomorphism of metric spaces .

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Does there exist any $n>1$ the two metric spaces $C[0,1]$ under the uniform metric and  $\mathbb R^n$ under the Euclidean metric, homeomorphic ???

Actually, I was thinking about this problem during proving  path-connectedness of  $C[0,1]$. Of couse, it is . And as the degrees of freedom on $C[0,1]$ is much more than that in $\mathbb R$, then they can't be homeomorphic .

But, removing countably many points from both $\mathbb R^n$ for $n>1$, and $C[0,1]$ makes them still path-connected .

But, thinking in an eerie sense, as a vector space, $C[0,1]$ is infinite dimensional, but $\mathbb R^n$'s are not for any $n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^n$ are not homeomorphic for any $m>n$, so in that sense it seems that the statement might be false .

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ I thought  the other way, what if I could disprove the statement ???

First of all, $card(C[0,1]) = card(\mathbb R^n)  = 2^{\aleph_0}$ .

Secondly, both are seperable, the former is due to Stone-Weierstrass theorem  and the latter due to $\mathbb Q^n$ .

Thirdly, neither is totally bounded, the former one has a subset of all constant functions of positive integers $\{1,2,3,4,....\}$ and the latter one due to non-compactness .

Now, I was thinking to prove the statement true by considering the fact of decimal representation of each point in  $\mathbb R^n$, $n>1$ , but I don't find any assignment, even at least for continuity .

Now, I need serious help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb R^n$, there are compact sets whose interior is not empty. This doesn't happen in $\mathcal C[0,1]$, since there no closed ball is compact. In fact, since $\mathcal C[0,1]$ is infinite-dimensional and its metric is induced by the $\sup$ norm, you know that [the closed unit ball is not compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/557405/446262), which is equivalent to the assertion that *no* closed ball is compact. But then the interior of any compact subset of $\mathcal C[0,1]$ is empty, since, if $K\subset\mathcal C[0,1]$ is compact and if $f\in\mathring K$, then there is a $r>0$ such that $B(f,r)\subset K$, which implies that $\overline{B(f,r)}\subset\overline K=K$. But this is impossible, since then $\overline{B(f,r)}$ would be compact too, and we have already seen that that does not occur.

Comment: Sir, a closed subspace of $C[a,b]$ is compact iff it's uniformly bounded and equicontinuous. But the family $\{ Sin kt | k \in \mathbb N\}$ is not equicontinuous on $[0,2π]$ . Does this fact imply your answer ???

Comment: I don't see how. I was just thinking that $C[0,1]$ is an infinite-dimensional normed space and that therefore the closed unit ball is not compact. But this implies that no closed ball is compact.

Comment: Sir, can you please explain me a little bit the fact you stated ??? I am not able to understand . It will be better if you edit your answer to elaborate this fact .

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now. If it is not, feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: I am extremely thankful to you,Sir !!! ☺️☺️☺️